# How do I display SQL query data in tabular format in HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which retrieves two columns from a table based on a 'location'.

The following table:

```
content_id     content_title
234            Fink, James
90             Merylou, Jane
45             Marcy, Kim
112            Bower, John
34             Alset, Mike
```

was generated by the following query:

```
DECLARE @strLocation varchar(200)
SET @strLocation = 'Ridge'

SELECT [content_id], [content_title]
FROM [content]
WHERE [folder_id] = '188'
AND (content_html LIKE '%'+@strLocation+'%')
```

The query looks into the `content_html` column and looks for the variable.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input type=text size=50 id="txtPhysByLoc" runat="server" /><input type=button value="Go" />
<br />
<div>
    <table border=0>
        <span id="writeTable"></span>
    </table>
</div>
```

My C# code-behind so far looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   string cString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=Dbase;User Id=efv;Password=st@tl;";
   SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
   Conn.Open();
}
```

How can I use the query along with my C# code to generate a table? Or use another ASP.net control to show the tabular data?

Comment: Simplest would be: Use a `GridView`, put that in ASPX page, in code behind execute your command, get a result set back in DataTable and then bind it to the GridView.

Comment: Can I just use one SQL command and separate by `;` for each line?

Comment: Short Answer: Yes. If the only command you want to execute is the one in question, then you don't need multiple statements. Instead you should pass the parameter from your Code behind, construct the SQL command in code behind and then get the result.

Comment: My query is one command but it's nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsContent" ConnectionString="<%$ connectionStrings.connectionString %>" SelectCommandType="text" SelectCommand="your query here">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent" DataSourceID="sdsContent">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <%# Eval("content_title").ToString() %>
   <br/>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

This should write something like:

```
     Fink, James
     Merylou, Jane
     Marcy, Kim
     Bower, John
     Alset, Mike
```

The

```
     <%$ connectionStrings.connectionString %>
```

part selects the conn property from webconfig (if you have already set-up that.)

Comment: Can I pass this: `Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=DBase;User Id=efv;Password=st@tl;` as the connection string instead?

Comment: `<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsContent" ConnectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;User Id=efd;Password=test;" SelectCommandType="text" SelectCommand="DECLARE @strLocation varchar(200) SET @strLocation = 'Ridge' SELECT [content_id], [content_title] FROM [content] WHERE [folder_id] = '188' AND (content_html LIKE '%'+@strLocation+'%')"></asp:SqlDataSource><asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent" DataSourceID="sdsContent"><ItemTemplate><%# Eval("content_title").ToString() %><br/><div style="clear:both;"></div></ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>`

Comment: I get the following error: `
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'content'.`

Comment: missplled table-name or initial-catalog name is wrong or table is not created?

Comment: As my question suggests I have multiple line in my SQL query, maybe that is what is causing the issue?

Comment: Repeater gets all your query rows and repeats them

Comment: You can give that sqldatasource some parameters(using brackets againg into its opening and closing) if you want to make it more "dynamic". Good game.